# Include a library without npm or bower

Tags: angularjs, promise, es6-promise

I am using angularjs 1.4 as my front-end framework, i want to include this library 
https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

but i do not have bower or npm setup in my front-end application. I am new to this field.

I have tried to include the library like below:

```
<script src="js/promise.min.js"></script>
```

and then placed code below in the index.html after i have included the library

```
import Promise from 'promise-polyfill'; 
if (!window.Promise) {
  window.Promise = Promise;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: why cant you have npm or bower included in your project? that would be better for maintenance as well

Comment: i am using sublime text editor

Comment: do `bower init` in that folder and then do `bower install`

Comment: my project has been developed without npm or bower on front-end side, it would a nightmare to setup at this point and honestly i do not know how to do it, i didn't find any good tutorial online to setup bower or npm on front-end side.

Comment: @entre i get this error when i run `bower init` : 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It would be a nightmare to go on development without package management. Trust me, you should refactor that and include npm/bower.

Comment: How did you setup es6 application without nodejs and npm?

Comment: Here is a link to get you started on MEAN stack, most of your existing code can still be reused and it will be easy as cake to add any further dependencies.  https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

Comment: @PaulsonPeter i am working on plain plain JS includes at the moment. all the libraries are included like `<script src="js/promise.min.js"></script>` this

Comment: Nice, so install your packages with bower and include your ressources by using the bower ressource path. Should be done in 15-30 Mins.

Comment: install chocolatey, then install nodejs, then do `npm install -g bower`... you might feel why should i install xyz softwares and stuff.. but trust me, it would be worth the effort.... better way to manage dependencies

Comment: @entre thanks for our help :) 
how can i include the above mentioned library in my application after i have setup bower?

Comment: once you do bower install... you just need to specify script tag like you do for any other library

Comment: @entre i have setup bower and i still do not know how to use the above mentioned library in my application :(

Comment: did you run `bower install --save <library-name>`?? then did you added the script tag in your application...

Comment: yes i did do it, but it doesn't solve my problem, promises are still not working.. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130507/discussion-between-arsinawaz-and-entre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently mix TypeScript with JavaScript. You could do it with JavaScript like:

```
define(["require", "exports", "promise-polyfill"], function (
    require, 
    exports, 
    promise_polyfill
    ){
        "use strict";
        if (!window.Promise) {
            window.Promise = promise_polyfill.default;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day!